# iterate over pyspark dataframe columns

Tags: python, iterator, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following `pyspark.dataframe`:

```
age  state  name    income
21    DC    john    30-50K
NaN   VA    gerry   20-30K
```

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of `df.isnull().sum()` (from pandas) which produces:

```
age      1
state    0
name     0
income   0
```

At first I tried something along the lines of:

```
null_counter = [df[c].isNotNull().count() for c in df.columns]
```

but this produces the following error:

```
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Similarly, this is how I'm currently iterating over columns to get the minimum value:

```
class BaseAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, report, struct):
        self.report = report
        self._struct = struct
        self.name = struct.name
        self.data_type = struct.dataType
        self.min = None
        self.max = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Column: %s>' % self.name


class BaseReport:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.columns_list = df.columns
        self.columns = {f.name: BaseAnalyzer(self, f) for f in df.schema.fields}

    def calculate_stats(self):
        find_min = self.df.select([fn.min(self.df[c]).alias(c) for c in self.df.columns]).collect()
        min_row = find_min[0]
        for column, min_value in min_row.asDict().items():
            self[column].min = min_value

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.columns[name]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Report>'

report = BaseReport(df)
calc = report.calculate_stats()

for column in report1.columns.values():
if hasattr(column, 'min'):
    print("{}:{}".format(column, column.min))
```

which allows me to 'iterate over the columns'

```
<Column: age>:1
<Column: name>: Alan
<Column: state>:ALASKA
<Column: income>:0-1k
```

I think this method has become way to complicated, how can I properly iterate over ALL columns to provide vaiour summary statistcs (min, max, isnull, notnull, etc..)  The distinction between `pyspark.sql.Row` and `pyspark.sql.Column` seems strange coming from pandas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
names = df.schema.names
for name in names:
    print(name + ': ' + df.where(df[name].isNull()).count())
```

You can see how this could be modified to put the information into a dictionary or some other more useful format.

Comment: This looks promising, although I end up with a `TypeError: Can't convert 'method' object to str implicitly`

Comment: my schema is as follows : `['individual_id',
 'first_name',
 'last_name',
 'house_number',
 'street_name',
 'city',
 'state',
 'zip',
 'county_name',
 'age',
 'gender',
 'birthdate',
 'null_col',
 'ind_politicalparty',
 'ind_vendorethnicity',
 'dma',
 'cd',
 'hh_income']`

Comment: So it seems the underlying `str` type is causing the problems more or less at this point?  After the edit the error turns into `TypeError:  Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

thanks for the help!

Comment: That is odd. I created a df using the values you showed in the question and everything works as expected. Seems like maybe some kind of mixed data types in one of the columns possibly.

Comment: hmm...You're likely right in that there are other data types in another column, I provided an example that doesn't include all the types i'm working with (pretty much one of each type)

I'm wondering if a `Column.cast` beforehand would be necessary

Comment: Just an update, using a str() wrapped around `name` and `df.where(df[name]...` ended up working out to get past the dif `TypeErrors`

thanks for your help!  Going to look more into using `df.where` get more used to the working with pyspark dataframes.  Would you recommend any good reads for tips w/ pyspark? Everything i come across tends to be the standard parallelized wordcount, etc..

Comment: I learned spark in a Data Science program. So your best bet may be going to meetups or networking with someone with some experience who's brain you can pick. Otherwise, I just read the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html), and lots of looking for examples here. I have an O'Reilly book about learning spark, but it is written for 1.6 and really didn't help me out any more than reading the documentation online.

Comment: makes sense.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I've been trying to get around `TypeError: condition should be string or Column` while trying to use `set_null = df.filter((lambda x: self.df[x].isNull().count()).collect()` I understand that `df.filters` takes a string or column but want if i want to pass it this function?  Is that possible?

Comment: I would go ahead and write up another question, include your reasoning, goal, and what you have tried so far. It will be easier to help out that way and the moderators don't really like conversations being carried out in comments like this.

Comment: There is a missing ")" in your code. Should be `print(name + ': ' + df.where(df[name].isNull())).count()'`

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one :

```
nullDf= df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]) 
nullDf.show()
```

it will give you a list of columns with the number of null its null values.